# Controller doesn't seem to be running

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Nothing in my controller seems to be working. So, I have checked the the network Tab of Google Chrome web developpement and I have noticed that the Controller file isn't running. I have Ctrl Find the name of my controller and I can't find it. Here's a print sceen of it.

[image]

Here is my main app file

App.js

```
Ext.application({
name: 'UniSelect',

requires: ['Ext.MessageBox',],

controller: ['Controleur'],

views: ['Main','ListeClient'],

model: ['ListeClient'],  

store: ['ListeClient'],

icon: {
    '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
    '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
    '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
    '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
},

isIconPrecomposed: true,

startupImage: {
    '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
    '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
    '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
    '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
    '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
    '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
},

launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('UniSelect.view.Main'));
},

onUpdated: function() {
    Ext.Msg.confirm(
        "Application Update",
        "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
        function(buttonId) {
            if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    );
}
});
```

The console doesn't even print the "RUNS" string that is at the very beginning of my controller file.

Controleur.js

```
console.log('RUNS');

Ext.define('UniSelect.controller.Controleur', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

requires: ['Ext.MessageBox'],                  

config: {
    refs: {

        liste: '#listeclient',

        liste: {
            selector: '#ListeClient',
            xtype: 'listeclient',
            autoCreate: true,
            forceCreate: true
        }


    },
    control: {
        liste: {
            itemtap: 'selectionClient'
        },
    }
},

selectionClient: function() {

    console.log('itemTap-RUNS');

  },

launch: function() {

    this.selectionClient();
    console.log('heyeye');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the config array in your application definition should be `controllers` not `controller`.

Comment: I have just tried it. It doesn't change anything. :S

Comment: Are there any 404s in the network tab?  And is your controller in the `controller` folder?

Comment: I haven't found any 404 problem in the network tab and my controller is definitively in my controller folder.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it finally works. I clicked at the controller file in my IDE (Eclipse) and I selected "Run on server" to run it.

I dont know why it didn't work when I was just building the project and running the project as a whole.

Thank you for your help chinabuffet